# How does one submit a transaction to the network using the blockchain.info API?

Tags: blockchain.info, api, raw-transaction

I am currently working on a project which makes use of the blockchain.info api (php). Could anybody please tell me how to use this api to submit transactions to the network?

Comment: What do you mean with "send data over block chain network"? Are you asking how to submit raw transactions?

Comment: yes exactly same

Answer (score 3):

To broadcast Bitcoin transaction using blockchain.info you have to send a post request to https://blockchain.info/pushtx with `tx=yourRawTransaction`.

I would suggest you run your own node because you may face some rate limit.

Comment: is there a way to send it to the testnet?

Comment: Not on blockchain.info, you may do it on your own server or look for some other blockchains.

Comment: that's shitty.  I've found that blockcypher will do it