# Bitcoin Testnet API that allows transaction lookup and submission of raw transactions

Tags: api, testnet, blockexplorer

I'm looking for a well developed, maintained and stable API allowing to access bitcoin testnet. Something like Infura for Ethereum. Googling gives many results, but can somebody point me out what is really in use?
In the moment for me BlockCypher looks the best, but can I really trust it?
It would be nice if the API was free, but it not necessarily has to be.
Cheers

Comment: run a testnet node?

Comment: Not an option. I need to build a minimalistic microservice that will only need to perform few simple tasks on bitcoin network. Check few balances, sometimes send single TX. Setting up whole not will be overkill.

Answer (score 1):

[mempool.space](https://mempool.space/docs/api/rest) has a cool api, they allow push raw transaction, recover balance, etc. They support mainnet, testnet and signet.

Answer (score 0):

[Blockchain.com API](https://www.blockchain.com/api)  could be an option. I use it for checking incoming transactions and confirmations. It is free.

Comment: Can I use it to broadcast a raw hex transaction?

Comment: I'm not really sure about raw TX. But they have wallet api which can be used to perform transactions https://www.blockchain.com/api/blockchain_wallet_api

Comment: Looks like they do: https://bitcoin.stackexchange.com/a/74218/5406